# How to write a method in Ruby that increments a passed in string by X amount of random characters

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I vaguely remember utilizing incremental functions in Java, e.g.

```
for i = 0; i < 100; i++
```

I am stress testing a text box by adding a LOT of characters to the end of a sentence to see if the text box works under such circumstances. .succ is not helping me. im trying to add 100 randomized characters to the end of a string.

Comment: You could use `SecureRandom.base64`, this will generate a random base64 string. `SecureRandom.base64(75)` will get you to 100 characters. ref: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

Comment: looking into this right now... ill report back if it works!

Comment: `SecureRandom.hex` is an alternative if you want to ensure the string is purely alphanumeric.

Comment: As this is a pure-Ruby question `require 'securerandom' is needed to use `SecureRandom` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can work for you:

```
100.times.map{ ('a'..'z').to_a.sample }.join('')
#=> "jbcyklmcdaxzpucrrlguzfdmipnkmqllowziirdvcysjmyxirjnagoojazepxxmzzysonjicbjtgqinkvenastfmuvayefrxjjhn"
```

Or, to get more chars:

```
chars = [*('A'..'Z'), *('a'..'z'), *('0'..'9')]
100.times.map{ chars.sample }.join('')
#=> "3kwsbKYTmXR9qmmC1JDdAkIP1tqA89L0ABF1et2drpPMUVP01qUHbmynB4iOzsGrmYzCdpva98boqoR2q6tIcOAvNb0ZiQ9tkkLr"
```